# Data from relational table is not saving yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

Im trying to save data using editable widget. it works when the data is from the user table but it doesnt work when its from a relational table. It works before when i havent done the sorting and filtering but when thats done, it doesnt work now which im really confused. I cant really found an example that is as my case here. Some debugging that i did seems like there no data went to post after clicking submit but i cant seem to find what the error is.Example here is `ethnic` which have a `ethnic_id` column in user table and referencing to user Ethnic table. What could possibly caused this error?

**__gridview column**

```
    [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'ethnic',
        'hAlign' => 'center',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'value' => 'ethnic.ethnic_name',
        'editableOptions' => [
            'size' => 'lg',
            'placement' => 'bottom',
            'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
            'data' => \frontend\models\common\RefUserEthnic::getDropDownList(),
        ],
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'prompt' => 'Select Ethnicity...'],
        'readonly' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return (!$model->status); // do not allow editing of inactive records
        },
    ],
```

**UserController**

```
public function actionIndex1() {
    $searchModel = new UserActiveSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
        $userId = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
        $user = User::findOne($userId);

        $post = [];
        $out = Json::encode(['output' => '', 'message' => '']);
        $posted = current($_POST['User']);
        $post['User'] = $posted;
        if ($user->load($post)) {
            $user->update();
            $output = '';
            $out = Json::encode(['output' => $output]);
            }
            echo $out;
            return;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('index1', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

**userSearch model**

```
public function search($params, $type = '') {
    $query = User::find();

    $query->joinWith("ethnic as eth", "eth.id=user.ethnic_id");

    // add conditions that should always apply here
    switch ($type) {
        case 'payrollList':
            $query->where("status in (9,10) AND (staff_id <> '' AND staff_id IS NOT NULL)");
            break;
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['ethnic'] = [
        'asc' => ['eth.ethnic_name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['eth.ethnic_name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];


    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
                'id' => $this->id,
                'status' => $this->status,
                'status' => $this->status,])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'auth_key', $this->auth_key])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'staff_id', $this->staff_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'password', $this->password])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'eth.ethnic_name', $this->ethnic])


    ;

    switch ($type) {
        case 'payrollList':
            if (!array_key_exists('sort', $params)) {
                $query->orderBy(['staff_id' => SORT_ASC]);
            }
            break;
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Provided some more info in comments as i dont want to keep editing this question.

Comment: Further info is when using `ethnic` as the attribute, the value of data/attribute taken like 1 or 2 or 3 or so on which is actually the `ethnic_id`, is taken in `_POST` as `ethnic` and not `ethnic_id`. So this is where the complications come from but I cant really found the solution for my case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a relational attribute issue. the `attribute` and `value` both is referring to the **ethnic** table means there is no reference to the **user** table. To fix this, `attribute` is set to `ethnic_id` for a reference to the **user** table and `value` is set to `ethnic.ethnic_name` as a reference to **ethnic** table.

```
    [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'ethnic_id',
        'label' => 'Ethnic',
        'hAlign' => 'center',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'value' => 'ethnic.ethnic_name',
        'filter' => \frontend\models\common\RefUserEthnic::getDropDownList(),
        'editableOptions' => [
            'size' => 'lg',
            'placement' => 'bottom',
            'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
            'data' => \frontend\models\common\RefUserEthnic::getDropDownList(),
        ],
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'prompt' => 'Select Ethnicity...'],

    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try using `save()` instead of `update()` in your controller.

So it becomes like this: `$user->save()`

Comment: Tried that and it still is the same. either `update` or `save`, and either with validation or no validation  `save(false)`.